# What is the academic consensus on footnote citations?

Tags: citations

Not really found a good answer on this online.

There seems to be a wide variation in the usage of footnoes in publications. While some authors use an APA format for every citation, even non-academic, e.g.:

> (New York Times, 2018)

Some authors would use footnotes such as:

> 1: The New York Times published an extensive analysis that details ...

Another example would be

> **Footnote:** See Authors et al. (2018) for an application of the model to evaluate the loss due to disasters in South America

What is your view on that?

- I spot a general trend that if there is a definitive, concise statement, the citations are kept in text
- If there is something more to add (so not "these are the results (..., 2018)" but rather "there is an extensive debate about xyz, (...,2017) lays it out in detail" - authors tend to use footnotes

I am a master thesis student that finalizes his thesis with the request of the professor to orient myself on a certain journal since he encouraged me to publish the results.

Comment: As stated, you are asking for opinions. That puts it off topic.

Comment: Mechanical style issues such as this will depend on the place you want to publish. Different editors have different requirements. Even different departments in one university may have different requirements. You will need to consult with the person(s) in charge of the place you want to publish.

Comment: Potentially an interesting question, but poll questions like "what is your view on this?" are not what we do here. What do you _really_ want to know? The pros and cons of this system? Why it went out of favor? Whether such a system is appropriate when the choice is left to the author?

Answer (score 12):

There is a wide variety of conventions, both between disciplines and between journals/conferences within a discipline. There is absolutely no single "academic consensus" we could point you to here.

Since you already have a specific journal in mind to submit to, I would very much recommend you take a look at its Guide for Authors, and/or look at recent papers published in that journal as to how they deal with these kinds of references. Since you plan on submitting (a version of) your thesis there, I would presume you already read and cited a number of papers from that journal, so much of your work is probably already done. And if papers in that journal follow different conventions, that probably means that the journal is flexible, so you can choose whatever approach you like best. (I personally dislike footnotes and overuse parentheses.)